# delete string date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table on datebase: id, mark, date.

The  date format like this: `DD.MM.YYYY (DD: 01-31, MM: 01-12, YYYY: 0000-9999)`

I need write query Mysql on php, that delete line which has difference between record and present time more that 7 days. Like this:

```
    mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password) OR die('Could not select database.');
    mysql_select_db($this->dbName) or die(mysql_error());
    $query = "delete from result where date-".date('d.m.Y')">7";//?
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

How write correct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
DELETE FROM result WHERE NOW()>`date` + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Tip: do not use function names and reserved words as column or table names.

Tip: do not use mysql_* functions since they are officially deprecated

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert your string to a mysql date using [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). Then, compare using regular mysql date arithmetic and comparison.

```
DELETE FROM result
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```